# Unit test a local JavaScript file against a remote URL

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, code-injection, functional-testing

How can I unit test a local JavaScript file against a remote URL? I've been working on this on and off for a few days now but can't quite figure it out yet.

I have a local file, with DOM manipulation, such as one called `app.js` that contains:

```
document.querySelector('p').textContent = 'This is a test.';
```

How can I then test this against a remote URL, such as http://example.com/, to ensure that the code successfully runs? The URL is not one that I control. Perhaps a solution that includes Selenium would make the most sense, but I'm not sure how I would also run my local JS file against the remote URL.

Such as with this pseudo code:

```
openUrl('http://example.com/', function() {
  inject('./app.js');

  element = document.querySelector('p');

  assertEquals('This is a test.', element.textContent);
});
```

I tried using Casper JS (based off of Phantom JS) and that was the most promising, but it doesn't wait for the DOM to finish loading before running assertions, so anything that's inside a jQuery $(document).ready() block will not have executed yet.

Here's what I got in Casper JS so far; the second assertion fails because it runs in a ready() block.

```
// app.js
$ = require('jquery');

$('p').first().text('test');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('h1').text('one');
});
```

And:

```
// test.js
var url = 'http://example.com/';
var script = 'Example/app.js';

casper.test.begin('Test', function suite(test) {
  casper.start(url, function() {
    casper.page.injectJs(script);

    // 'test' was added immediately, in app.js. This succeeds.
    test.assertTextExists('test');

    // 'one' runs in a $(document).ready() block. This assertion fails.
    test.assertTextExists('one');
  });

  casper.run(function() {
    test.done();
  });
});
```

Comment: What on earth does *"against a remote URL"* mean?

Comment: A URL that is not on my own computer, so not localhost.

Comment: http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html

Comment: Yes but Jasmine, Mocha etc. require that I have control of the HTML I'm testing against, too.

Comment: I re-read this a number of times and still don't get it. If you don't care about the URL you're testing it on, what's the problem?

Comment: How do I automate this test like a normal unit test? I do care about the URL I'm testing on, I'm not sure where I said I didn't... Unit test tools seem to either require that I test JS against a local HTML file, or on a remote URL that I control since I'd have to embed the JS test script into the page, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Casper, and I solved the problem of waiting for the DOM by simply using `casper.wait(100)`.

Some sample code (I haven't tested this but it should work; my actual code is much more complex). Run with `casperjs test casper.js`

**casper.js**

```
// Begin test suite.
casper.test.begin('Example', function(test) {
  // Start Casper.
  casper.start();

  // Open URL.
  casper.thenOpen('http://example.com/', function() {
    casper.page.injectJs('inject.js');
  });

  // Call the test. Wait for code to finish first.
  casper.wait(100, function() {
    test.assertExists('.element-added-by-injection');
  });

  // A second URL can even be opened.
  casper.thenOpen('http://google.com/', function() {
    casper.page.injectJs('google.js');
  });

  casper.wait(100, function() {
    test.assertExists('.another-element-we-added');
  });

  casper.run(function() {
    test.done();
  });
});
```

**inject.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$(function() {
  $('p').after('<div class="element-added-by-injection">Test</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout phantom.js its a headless browser, which can load urls, run jquery on this, and do asserts if you like.

You can then test you local environment, and run the same script for the remote too.

phantom.js is very popular and there are a lot of plugins available for it.

Comment: How do I use Phantom JS specifically for this though? I tried Phantom via Casper JS and I almost was able to succeed with it, since they both allow to inject JS into a remote URL, but they don't want for the DOM to finish, so any code in jQuery's $(document).ready() block is run too late.

Comment: well, you dont need the ready event.. just run your script, because the page already finished loading @Gary

Comment: My own script needs to be run within the ready event. Yet Casper JS won't wait for the ready event, so my code within the ready event is executed too late.

Comment: Thanks, that led me to Casper's `load.finished` event. However, I can't seem to run any Casper assertions within these event blocks.